# ConfigurationProperties not loading with ContextConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, automated-tests

I am trying to run a test for a project converted to spring boot.  The test initially looked like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContextTestFnx.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners({
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
    DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class
})
```

While I did not author the test, the xml is defining a Derby data source and component scans instead of the real data source.  I changed it to this because I wanted it to find my application-test.properties.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContextTestFnx.xml"})

@SpringBootTest(properties = "spring.cloud.config.enabled=false")
@ActiveProfiles("test")


@TestExecutionListeners({
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
    DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class
})
```

The problem I am having is a key configuration property object is not being populated.  I believe the @ContextConfiguration is short circuiting the normal spring boot initialization.

I have tried adding this to the XML but it did not work

```
<bean class="com.myco.MailConfig"/>
```

The config object is pretty basic:

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@RefreshScope
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("mail")
public class MailConfig {

    private String                  baseURL;
    private String                  Subject;
    private String                  to;
    private String                  from;
    private String                  enabled;

    <public getters and setters omitted>

}
```

Is there a way to get my configuration object populated?